# Keys sticking/doubling with other keys

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a mid-2014 MacBook Pro which is still working well after all these years, except for one problem: the right Option key is doubling with the j and apostrophe keys, and something is making the semicolon key simultaneously trigger the audio mute/unmute option. The cost and/or effort required to replace the keyboard isn't worth it, so I have been limping along this way for a long time. Recently it dawned on me that I might be able to work around it through system settings. I remembered that you can remap modifier keys, so I went to the preferences for that and tried disabling Option. Like magic, my j and apostrophe keys work normally again! Then to fix the semicolon, I enabled the setting that makes the F-keys work without requiring Fn. Now semicolon triggers Mission Control (F10). OK, not ideal... but then I disabled the F10 Mission Control shortcut, and now the semicolon works normally!

Still, I would be happier if I could get the keys working normally again without a workaround. I did try to remove and blow air under some of them, but without any success, and removing the keys was nerve-racking. I couldn't get the j key off for fear of destroying it. Just wondering if anyone else has had a hardware problem like this and can suggest anything else to fix it. I'd really like to keep this laptop going for another year or two. Thanks!